# Flutter Android and IOS App Is Crash When I'm Using Confetti Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm using [Confetti](https://pub.dev/packages/confetti) Widget for Showing Some Animation but My Application is crashing. I have upgraded Flutter 3.7.1 and getting this issue. any one please help me.

I have clean flutter but nothing happens

Comment: without code its hard to understand.. did u try Running without Cofetti packages ..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's known issue of confetti package in Flutter 3.7. You have to upgrade your Flutter to greater then 3.7.2 Because its fixed in Flutter Version 3.7.2 So I'll suggest you to run `flutter upgrade` to update your flutter version